# SIGABRT and COREDUMP

Tags: unix, sigabrt, coredump

There was a coredump seen on an application on a server. According to the mdb output, it was found that it was caused due to a SIGABT signal being sent to the application.
Is it normal for an application to dump a core, in case it  a SIGABRT signal is sent to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html
Each signal has a default disposition and SIGABRT has CORE as default action.